# VB.net webrequest.uploadfile aborted error

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, webrequest

I use webrequest uploadfile fuction. But I have error for big files in slow network. So I think maybe buffer or something help me

My code

```
Private Shared Function GetFileUploadResponse(ByVal fileToUpload As String, ByVal accessToken As String, ByVal uploadUrl As String) As UploadResponse
        Dim client = New WebClient()
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " & accessToken)

        Dim responseBytes = client.UploadFile(uploadUrl, fileToUpload)

        Dim responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes)

        Dim response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of UploadResponse)(responseString)

        Return response



    End Function
```

when I try upload bigger 100 mb files error aborted.

I found this code but this is for FTP. I use normal webupload. I try to modify my code but give error every try

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest =
    WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip")
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

Using fileStream As Stream = File.OpenRead("C:\local\path\file.zip"),
      ftpStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    Dim read As Integer
    Do
        Dim buffer() As Byte = New Byte(10240) {}
        read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        If read > 0 Then
            ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, read)
            Console.WriteLine("Uploaded {0} bytes", fileStream.Position)
        End If
    Loop While read > 0
End Using
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution! But please don't edit your question to indicate that the problem has been solved. Stack Overflow doesn't work that way. Instead write your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted when time allows. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution found. problem about webclient timeout. this modifield webclient work good.

```
Public Class BigWebClient
    Inherits WebClient
    Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(ByVal address As System.Uri) As System.Net.WebRequest
        Dim x As WebRequest = MyBase.GetWebRequest(address)
        x.Timeout = 60 * 60 * 1000
        Return x
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the maximum file upload size on the server end, apparently yours is set to 100mb.

```
On the server:
Open IIS Manager.
Select the website with your site name.
Double-click on "Request Filtering".
Click "Edit Feature Settings" on the right hand side of the page.
In the dialogue window that opens you can see the "Maximum allowed content length" field. The default is 30mb, apparently yours is set to 100mb Let us say we want our files to be up to 1GB, then we would need to put "1073741824" there.
```